# Regex in xsl:template

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

How do I write this code in a correct way?

```
<xsl:template match="emp[matches(., 'Note(0[3-9]|1[0,1,6,8])_Line(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9])_Col00')]">
    <xsl:copy use-attribute-sets="NoteNumber">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The above code returns a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` error in OxygenXML.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not seeing any issue with this piece of code!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the fragment of code you have posted; the problem lies elsewhere. Please (a) eliminate anything that's not necessary to reproduce the bug (e.g. the attribute set), and (b) make it a complete repro: stylesheet plus source document plus any relevant Oxygen configuration details.

Comment: Yes @MichaelKay, you are right. I think it has something to do with the Saxon version in OxygenXML. I'll try to upgrade it to version 9.8 (I have 9.7) and see if this will work.